# Locate the latest version (by filename) of a specific file within a specific folder

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for your help...

Originally, I had a folder (named "reports") where an xml version of my the latest schedule for my app lived. The naming conventions for this xml file is "schedule-'currentdate'-'currenttime'.xml (ex: "schedule-20130313-070004.xml") I had no problem locating this file using scandir and sorting the folder contents in descending order and then taking the first.

My problem now is that another type of report has been added to the folder (ex: "roster-20130313-07004.xml") My former method no longer works. I'm outputting this information in two different places (schedule.xml on the schedule page, and roster.xml on the roster page) How can I search this folder, find the most current file, according to the date, and make sure that each report ends up where it's supposed to?

Comment: so do you need to find the latest version of roster AND schedule? or just the latest of either?

Comment: I need to find the latest version of roster, that way the most accurate and current output will be correct on the roster page (same goes for schedule) but once I've figured out how to do one, I can apply it to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple such as

```
$files = scandir($dir);
$report = [];
$schedu = [];
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    if ( strpos( $file, 'report') !== false ) {
        $report << $file;
    } else {
        $schedu << $file;
    }
}

//sort arrays
```

should work just fine. This will take the original array of directory results and place them  into two new arrays, depending on whether or not the contain the string 'report'.

Comment: then sorting the arrays similarly to what i had been doing (descending)?

Comment: If that gives you the most recent files, then yes. It will essentially separate them out as though they were two individual directories, and allow you to use your previous method of finding the most recent documents.

Comment: What that method is doing is pushing values onto the appropriate array, rather than having array( [0] => report, [1] => schedule) you'll have array([0] => report) and array([0] => schedule).

Comment: got it working. i appreciate you looking into this for me - thanks!